# Margin not getting applied to a multiline text in whole class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is html code

```css
.sectionToc {
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #095D18;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sectionToc a {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #0D6A48;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subsectionToc {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #0D6A48;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.subsectionToc a {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #169A9A;
  font-size: 19.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<br /><span class="sectionToc">25 <a 
    href="#x1-2600025" id="QQ2-1-26">URLs,Hyperlinks and Bookmarks</a></span>
<br /><span class="sectionToc">26 <a 
    href="#x1-2700026" id="QQ2-1-27">Header and Footer</a></span>
<br />&#x00A0;<span class="subsectionToc">26.1 <a 
    href="#x1-2800026.1" id="QQ2-1-28">Header and Footer for all pages</a></span>
<br />&#x00A0;<span class="subsectionToc">26.2 <a 
    href="#x1-2900026.2" id="QQ2-1-29">Customising Headers and Footers for different pages</a></span>
<br /><span class="sectionToc">
```

The problem is that when window resizes (for example on mobile device) the second line in subsection doesn't have margin on its left. For example try resizing window and see how the subsection 26.2 gets displayed. The second line doesn't have any margin. It doesn't inherit margin from its parent class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `.subsectionToc` span wraps across multiple lines then the width is too narrow. What you need is an element with `display:block` rather than `inline`. `<div>` will do. Then you also won't need the `<br>`s in between.

```css
.sectionToc {
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #095D18;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sectionToc a {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #0D6A48;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subsectionToc {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #0D6A48;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.subsectionToc a {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #169A9A;
  font-size: 19.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionToc">
  25 <a href="#x1-2600025" id="QQ2-1-26">URLs,Hyperlinks and Bookmarks</a>
</div>
<div class="sectionToc">
  26 <a href="#x1-2700026" id="QQ2-1-27">Header and Footer</a>
</div>
<div class="subsectionToc">
  26.1 <a href="#x1-2800026.1" id="QQ2-1-28">Header and Footer for all pages</a>
</div>
<div class="subsectionToc">
  26.2 <a href="#x1-2900026.2" id="QQ2-1-29">Customising Headers and Footers for different pages</a>
</div>
<div class="sectionToc">
```

Also, `margin` is not an inherited property.

Answer (score 0):

That's how `span` works, it is going to the next line just because of overflow but in mobile screen, the line below is also a part of the same line. So, the margins will only take effect at the start of the line.

Change all the `span` to `div` if you want to have them aligned to the same margin. And also use negative `margin-top` to look it nice.

Here's the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2o9m0qu6/12/)** and code below:

```css
.sectionToc {
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #095D18;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.sectionToc a {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #0D6A48;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subsectionToc {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #0D6A48;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.subsectionToc a {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 248, 248, 0.76);
  color: #169A9A;
  font-size: 19.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<br />
<div class="sectionToc">25 <a href="#x1-2600025" id="QQ2-1-26">URLs,Hyperlinks and Bookmarks</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="sectionToc">26 <a href="#x1-2700026" id="QQ2-1-27">Header and Footer</a>
</div>
<br />&#x00A0;
<div class="subsectionToc">26.1 <a href="#x1-2800026.1" id="QQ2-1-28">Header and Footer for all pages</a>
</div>
<br />&#x00A0;
<div class="subsectionToc">26.2 <a href="#x1-2900026.2" id="QQ2-1-29">Customising Headers and Footers for different pages</a>
</div>
<br />
```